Kafka transaction crash in the middle of two phase commit
I am learning about Kafka and I am trying to understand different concepts in it.
I read this article: https://developer.confluent.io/courses/architecture/transactions/
And I saw that picture: 
So I am wondering what will happen in case of failure in the middle of step 8:

successfully committed to P0
successfully committed to P1
Coordinator or the node in the bottom fails (is there a difference in the two scenarios?)

So the messages in P0 and P1 will be visible to be read (even from consumers with read_committed isolation level), but the message in P7 will not be available for read.
So my question is:

Here we loose this all or nothing, right?
How the system will try to recover from that?
If the coordinator is dead, what will happen with the messages in P7 which are not mark as commited? They will stop consumers with read_commited isolation level to progress (as far as I understood from the documentation)

Hope that the questions makes sence. I wasn't able to find answers for these.
Thanks in advance!
